# why does linux driver use semaphore and spin_lock simutaneously?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I come across a linux driver code that use semaphore and spinlock at the same time:

```
struct semaphore lock;
spinlock_t int_lock;
unsigned long flag;

void dequeue()
{
down_interruptible(lock);
spin_lock_irqsave(int_lock,flag);
}
```

is it necessary to use the two together?

Comment: Sometimes. `down_interruptible` can sleep, so cannot be used in code that needs to synchronize with interrupt handlers and interrupt back-end handlers. So the `down_interruptible` could be being used to synchronize with other user-level tasks, and the `spin_lock_irqsave` could be being used to synchronize with an interrupt handler or back-end.

Comment: "spin_lock_irqsave" is called immediately after "down_interruptible" inside one function in an ioctl system call from userspace.I wonder is it necessary to use the two at the same time?

Comment: Well, it depends what the function does and what the rest of the code does. It's hard to tell from the code fragment you have posted.